# What should the "model" be?

Tags: php, class, model-view-controller, model

At first I was the impression that this is the class for a single database record. Some frameworks do that.

Then I thought it represents a collection, like a class that does select queries and manages a bunch of records.

Then I read here an answer saying that the Model should be just a folder containing a bunch of classes.

So which one is it?

Comment: This Martin Fowler article might help: http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html#ModelViewController

Comment: Tacking on the wikipedia in case that's helpful for @katie: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

Comment: I read like all the articles on the internet about mvc and it's still a little bit confusing :(

Comment: @katie did you read the articles about architecture or about frameworks?

Comment: Frameworks I guess. They are mentioned everywhere when you google mvc

Comment: The smallest representation of your application not requiring a user interface is the model. Practically this can be any number of things but we have found that in *most* PHP applications with a database that you can do ALL of the heavy lifting in the database (utilizing stored procedures and triggers) including business logic. For less capable databases, SQLite for instance, business logic has to be moved to PHP for all but the simplest of interactions. YMMV

Comment: It's worth noting that many frameworks (like Rails and the PHP frameworks heavily influenced by it) conflate or combine the model with ORM, or "[object-relational mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping)." This is the origin of the common misconception that the model is "the class for a single database record." In fact, while it can be convenient to shoehorn database logic into the model, MVC as a pattern does not require a database at all, and can (and often should) be implemented completely separately.

Comment: Model is a layer, not a single thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either of them. If you have a really simple application that just queries the database and shows the result somewhere, the database can be the model. If you have a complex application that does some stuff with the data, validates it, changes it, sends events on change or simply a bit too much to write that huge query in each place you would like to use the same part, you should use manager classes.

Another way of looking at it, is that the model is the application's core logic. No user interface involved in the design. You should provide a simple way to communicate to the core of your app. If the plain database is enough, then it's enough.

That said I find it really unlikely that the database will be enough. Anything apart from a single "list this table" should have a proper model with proper classes and have the database as a storage provider which has a high performance search engine built into it.

Comment: -1: database is NOT a model and "manager classes" as a design smell.

Comment: @tereško I understand how it smells, but early on when you're just doing a simple select, it can be enough. When there is a modification involved, that's the part where you need a proper abstraction layer away from the database. Your application may only exist to view the data, and not modify it. The "manager class" is only there to be able to better understand what it does. From the interface it can be a fully blown model, but inside you can keep it as a simple wrapper up until you need it to be a proper model.

Answer (score 1):

- **The central component of MVC, the model, captures the behavior of the application in terms of its problem domain, independent of the user interface. The model directly manages the data, logic and rules of the application.**
- A view can be any output representation of information, such as a chart or a diagram; multiple views of the same information are possible, such as a bar chart for management and a tabular view for accountants.
- The third part, the controller, accepts input and converts it to commands for the model or view.

Hence from your options, it's the closest to the 2nd option i.e.

> it represents a collection, like a class that
>   does select queries and manages a bunch of records.

Comment: I would note that in large application (and MVC pattern is **not* meant for the small ones) the "view" part of triad can be as large as "model". Especially is you have a project with multiple user interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Model is not just data. Models are the are collection of classes that represent your data and the relationships and the business logic.